# Rdlc report expression not formatted correctly. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: rdlc

What is wrong with this tablix group expression?

```
 =First(Fields!ROWNO.Value, "QuestionPaperData")
```

During edit, I am not allowed to share image. I could not read the full message. I am still struggling for exact design.

Comment: Tablix group->Expressions dialog box. Here in Set expressions section the Fields!ROWNO.Value is underlined in colour. please help

Comment: Finally it's working. How to proceed next to close question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the expression like this =Fields!ROWNO.Value

Comment: Thanks for your interest to answer my question. I appreciate your effort. but, please see the comment i think you missed somehow. I could able to show as required for my rdlc report.